# Ubuntu 10.04 - Display Issues

Tags: ubuntu, video

We have a Visio VX32L tv in our lobby that displays a web page welcoming visitors to our company. Currently there is a Dell GX260 workstation running windows xp that is used to display the web page. I am trying to replace the windows install with Ubuntu but I am having issues with the video.

I have installed 10.04 in my office with the workstation hooked up to a 17" NEC monitor. Everything works fine, the display is correct and I have plenty of options to change the screen resolution etc. I then take the workstation up to the lobby and hook it up and this is where the trouble starts. I get the Dell BIOS screen, no problem. Then it displays the start of the Ubuntu splash screen for a second and immediately goes away displaying "No Input Signal". I have reconnected it to the 17" monitor and set the resolution to one that I know the lobby screen supports but I receive the same results. The windows xp install displays fine and there were no special drivers needed. I had origianlly tried using 10.10 and it would display on both monitors but I had no options to change the screen resolution at either place. From what I found through Google, this was a common issue on 10.10 so I dropped back to 10.04. 10.04 is halfway there buts still not 100%. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am trying to introduce Ubuntu to our workplace but it is just not cooperating!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would check and see if you could generate a new Xorg.conf file for the monitor in the other room (use SSH to access the box). Back up the old one by moving it out of the /etc/X11/ directory to somewhere safe. While X will work on on monitor, I can pretty much guarantee all of the horizontal/vertical frequencies will be different on the big TV. You're better off starting with a clean Xorg.conf file so that it can generate everything for the new monitor.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I have looked for the xorg.conf file and it is not there, is it hidden?

Comment: You should be able to see it if you're logged in as root. Type 
`sudo find / |grep Xorg.conf` and see if it is listed anywhere. It should be there if its working on the other monitor, otherwise you may need to create one.

Comment: A default install of Ubuntu does not make use of `/etc/Xorg.conf`.

Comment: Aye. Xorg.conf disappeared around the time of version 9.10

Comment: The [Resolution section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) of the Ubuntu wiki is pretty detailed on configuring displays.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Thanks for the heads up - most of my knowledge is from Debian. I forgot Ubuntu has set out to do their own thing :) Sorry for misleading!